# jquery: I want to show a specific div when its corresponding link is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am a bit of a novice with jquery. Basically I want to show only the div that corresponds to the link clicked and hide the divs unrelated to that link.

Below is an example of what I want to do and the script I am struggling with. This is for Wordpress which is why "JQuery" is spelled out rather than just "$".

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
 var clickLink = [".link1", ".link1", ".link1"];
 var toggleDiv = ["#link1", "#link1", "#link1"];
 for (i=0; i < toggleDiv.length; i++) {
  jQuery(toggleDiv[i]).hide();
 }
 jQuery('#linkBank a').click(function() {
           for (i=0; i < clickLink.length; i++) {
             if (this.id == clickLink[i]) {
              jQuery(toggleDiv[i]).toggle();
             }
           }
           
           return false;
       });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="linkBank">
<a href="#" id="link1">First Link</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">Second Link</a>
<a href="#" id="link3">Third Link</a>
</div>

<div class="link1">You clicked on First Link</div>
<div class="link2">You clicked on Second Link</div>
<div class="link3">You clicked on Third Link</div>
```

Comment: You can create the `$` shortcut like this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of html data attributes and use that in order to know which element to show, that's the cleanest way and you don't depend on an array of values or ID values being identical to classes you wish to show. In this example, I named the 'data-show' html attribute and the value of it is basically the selector of the element you wish to select (eg '.sth' for elements with class 'sth', you could use #foo for an element with id 'foo' etc)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var $divs = jQuery('.toggling-divs');
        $divs.hide();
 jQuery('#linkBank a').click(function() {
           $divs.hide();
           var showDiv = jQuery(this).attr('data-show');
           jQuery(showDiv).show();
           
           return false;
       });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="linkBank">
<a href="#" id="link1" data-show=".first-link">First Link</a>
<a href="#" id="link2" data-show=".sth-else">Second Link</a>
<a href="#" id="link3" data-show=".foobar">Third Link</a>
</div>

<div class="first-link toggling-divs">You clicked on First Link</div>
<div class="sth-else toggling-divs">You clicked on Second Link</div>
<div class="foobar toggling-divs">You clicked on Third Link</div>
```

Comment: For some reason the "Run code snippet" feature isn't working but I will test it locally. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @figure2, works now. The formatting was a bit messed up and there was a space between '<' and 'a', that I missed, so that's why it wasn't working ;)